# Java anonymous inner class of List

Tags: java

I want to attach a method to a LinkedList object at run time via an anonymous inner class. Is this possible?

For example:

```
    LinkedList<String> paths = new LinkedList<String>() {
        void addAllIfNotNull(Collection<String> c) {
            if(c != null) {
                addAll(c);
            }
        }
    };
    paths.add(list1);
    paths.add(list2);
    paths.add(list3);
    ...
    paths.add(listN);
```

Without having to do a if(list_i is not null) addAll(list_i)
?

This doesn't look like it is possible because the LinkedList does not have an AddAllIfNotNull method. Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add a new method with a new signature, since the type stays `LinkedList<String>`.

The way to do what you want, is to overide the existing method `addAll()` from `LinkedList<T>`, this way :

```
    LinkedList<String> paths = new LinkedList<String>() {
        public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends String> c) {
            System.out.println("In overiden addAll");
            if(c != null) {
                return super.addAll(c);
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
    // This now works
    paths.addAll(null);
```

Comment: @DimaMaligin ??? I do call `super.addAll()` and I dont see why its a bad idea. It's a short cut for extending `LinkedList<T>`.

Comment: Yes you do thats y I removed the comment. Didnt see it there.

Comment: Not a bad solution, 1+, and certainly much better than райтфолд's answer. Use a static method? Serious?

Comment: are there side effects to this? Is it going to break code stuff if I pass it around? And what is the class of paths if there the implementation has been overridden? What is this pattern called? Is there a name? I see it in some places.

Comment: @doorfly This is just an override which wont be implemented by other instances of `LinkedList`. So if you want to reuse this in another `List` you will have to reoverride it.

Comment: @doorfly: I think that you're much better off using a non-inner stand-alone class for this.

Comment: If the need is only on one instance , then it's a very light weight solution.

Comment: @AbbéRésina I wouldn't call it light weight since it still creates the new class, its just non reusable.

Comment: For what I was looking for, I was not looking to define another class. I knew I could do that and make it work but I didn't want the boilerplate. His solution was exactly what I was looking for. In fact, I would have gotten it, but the parameterized Collection syntax threw me off. I tried Collection<String> c and that didn't work... it had to be Collection<? extends String>

Answer (score 6):

This is not possible via an anonymous inner class. It can be done with a non-anonymous inner class or a stand-alone class, but not anonymous since the compiler will have no way of recognizing the method since to the compiler the variable is of type `LinkedList`, and if you wanted to cast the variable, what would you cast it to since the type you want is anonymous?

Question for you: what happens when you try this? Does it compile when you try to call the method?

e.g.,

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class LinkedListFoo {
   public LinkedListFoo() {
      List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

      MyLinkedList<String> paths = new MyLinkedList<>();
      paths.addAllIfNotNull(list);     
   }

   // non-anonymous inner class
   private class MyLinkedList<T> extends LinkedList<T> {
      void addAllIfNotNull(Collection<T> c) {
         if(c != null) {
             addAll(c);
         }
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: No, does not compile because addAllIfNotNull is not a function on the linked list. Do you have an example of what you mean by named inner class?

Comment: @doorfly: for example.

Answer (score 0):

I think Hovercraft's answer should be accepted, but another option for you is to override some method on `LinkedList<T>`--say, `boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c)`, in which you could do the null check before calling `super.addAll(c)` (effectively preventing it from throwing `NullPointerException`). That way you can call `addAll` and still use an anonymous class. However, this technique should be used cautiously. `java.util.LinkedList#addAll` can be reasonably expected to throw the exception given a null parameter. Using a named class avoids that confusion.